# Can you set Flash Builder to kill previous runs when starting a fresh run?

Tags: flash-builder

I'd like Flash Builder to kill previous run instances when I run/debug.

It's driving me nuts that I can easily accumulate multiple instances of my project running outdated code if I don't go through and kill them individually each time I run.

Thank you

Comment: as i understand it, the debugger will disconnect from old instance when a new one is started (although swf itself will keep going). But yes, its a pain to have to manually close browser tabs - even opening new instances in same window would be useful.

Comment: I was verifying that just to document it when I think I found the best solution that exists, although not still what I perfectly wanted:

There is an unbound keybinding called "Terminate and Relaunch" in the general preferences which will terminate the run/debug that is currently connected to the debugger and start a new instance.  So if you only use this you can avoid accumulating outdated instances.

Putting this as an answer, but I hope someone can make something that doesnt require a change in flow (still be able to use the debug button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best answer I was able to find thanks to Lee Burrows:

There is an unbound keybinding called "Terminate and Relaunch" in the general preferences which will terminate the run/debug that is currently connected to the debugger and start a new instance.  So if you only use this you can avoid accumulating outdated instances.

Putting this as an answer, but I hope someone can make something that doesn't require a change in flow (still be able to use the debug button), and this will also not kill multiple instances if that somehow still happens.